# c# ZPL Binary Kits License

Tags: zpl

```
Hello, I am developing a program for my company. 
In this project, we need to implement a feature that previews zebra's zpl in C#. 
Therefore, I want to use an external library (Nuget), but the famous Labelary not only has restrictions on continuous use, but the company does not want security information to be passed on. 
Therefore, I want to use a Nuget package called Binary Kits, but this package also seemed to support how to use Labelary and its own viewer module. 
If I use Binary Kits' own viewer module, I wonder if there will be any problems such as my data being 
transferred to another place, or there being a limit on the number of preview uses.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de2hh.png)

```
I installed BinaryKits.Zpl.Viewer and these packages were downloaded automatically.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This looks to be a customer service question not a programming question, which would be off-topic here.  Please see: [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) and [Questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963).  Instead you should address licensing related questions directly to the author of BinaryKits.Zpl here: https://github.com/BinaryKits/BinaryKits.Zpl/issues

Comment: And it seems you already did: [Licensing Questions #143](https://github.com/BinaryKits/BinaryKits.Zpl/issues/143#issuecomment-1321692544): *There is no limit to preview images and it also does not require an external connection*

Comment: sorry. I do not speak English, so I am in a situation where I use a translator to ask questions and get answers. This site in English is still difficult for me to use properly. Let's get more familiar with this site. thank you